# Refreshing views inside an android fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

So I am making an app that uses and SQLite database. It has 3 swipeable tabs created using fragments and such.  In one tab I have a button that updates the SQL database and in another tab is a history of updates, or more specifically a purchase history.  In the history tab I have a scrollview with a tablelayout that I can successfully draw in the onCreateView method of that fragment, however I want it to update with new purchases as they are added to the database and I dont know how to do this.  I can tell the database is being updated because the new rows are added when the app is opened up again but I cant get the history fragment's view to be updated unless the app is closed and reopened. Any suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Cursor Loaders](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html) this way you can have dynamically updates on your interface as data changes.